# Load database values as k:v pairs into PHP, and then into JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database

I'm trying to load Chinese words as keys, and their English translations as values from a database into a php array so then I can use them on the client side in JavaScript. So I load the PHP key:value pairs into the JavaScript array and try to output the results.

Database setup:

[image]

```
    include 'php/DbConnect.php';
    $sql = $mysqli->query(
     "SELECT t.*, v.* 
     FROM task t 
     INNER JOIN vocabtask vt ON (t.id = vt.taskid)
     INNER JOIN vocab v ON (v.id = vt.vocabid)
     WHERE vt.taskid = 1");
    $wordsArray = array();

    while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
        $wordsArray[$row['chinese']] = $row['english'];
        //echo key : value pair
        echo "<br>".key($wordsArray) . ":" . $wordsArray[$row['chinese']];
    }
    var_dump($wordsArray);
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Echo output gives `Ni` as key for each value, which is wrong:

```
Ni: You
Ni: Him or Her
Ni: I
```

var_dump, however, gives correct `key:value` pairing:

```
array (size=3)
  'Ni' => string 'You' (length=3)
  'Ta' => string 'Him or Her' (length=10)
  'Wo' => string 'I' (length=1)
```

**JavaScript:**

```
    var words = [<?php echo '"'.implode('","', $wordsArray).'"' ?>];

    $.each(words, function(key, value) {
        console.log('stuff : ' + key + ", " + value);
    });
```

Console.log gives numbers for keys, and not the Chinese keys:

```
stuff : 0, You 
stuff : 1, Him or Her
stuff : 2, I
```

Question: if the `php` dump shows appropriate pairings of key (the Chinese word) to value (the English word), why am I getting this different outputs?

Answer (score 1):

`implode()` is not printing the keys of `$wordsArray` which is why the var `words` doesn't have the correct keys.

What you're really trying to achieve here is a string representation of a PHP array with Javascript syntax. A function that will do that for you is `json_encode()`

```
<?php echo "var words = ". json_encode($wordsArray) . ";";?>
```

More info here: https://www.php.net/json_encode

And the reason this line doesn't work:

```
echo "<br>".key($wordsArray) . ":" . $wordsArray[$row['chinese']];
```

Is because the `key()` function doesn't move the array pointer, hence you get a repeat of the same array key.

Comment: Hah, that's weird that key() wouldn't move along with the array. So to move the key, you would use data_seek, right? Also, can you explain `json_encode`?

Comment: I think what you're trying to do there is echo out the last element added to the array. I'd do it like this: `$v = end($array); echo key($array) . " : " . $v;`. `end` will make sure the pointer is on the last element. I've updated the answer to explain `json_encode` further. Does that cover what you need?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this?

```
var words = 
[<?php $result = [];
foreach($wordsArray as $key=>$value){
   $result[] = '"'.$key.'":"'.$value.'"';
}
echo implode(',', $result)
?>]
```